# How to create signed APK for Android, Cordova, Mac OS, Upload Certificate?

Tags: android, cordova

All the instructions I can find for creating a signed APK with Cordova for Android seem to have been created before Google's new app signing protocol.

I've created an app signing certificate in the Play Console and have an upload certificate.

I can create a signed APK in Android Studio, but I need to do it in Terminal (Mac OS).

I can't find any instructions that are current.

Can somebody provide such instructions?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured this out.

I created a build.json file and dropped it into my /www folder (I initially tried it in my /platforms/android folder but that file path didn't work).

`{
  "android": {
    "debug": {
     "keystore": "/path to jks file",
      "storePassword": "PW",
      "alias": "youralias",
      "password" : "pw",
      "keystoreType": "jks"
  },
   "release": {
    "keystore": "/path to jks file",
      "storePassword": "PW",
      "alias": "youralias",
      "password" : "pw",
      "keystoreType": "jks"
        }
    }
}`

Command line: `cordova build android --release --buildConfig build.json`

Since I'm not ready to increment a new version of my app, new version number, as required by the Play Console, I haven't tried uploading this new build, but I do have a signed APK.

Terminal provides you with a path to the new APK after `Built the following apk(s):`